# Java application working fine on win32 but not on win64

Tags: java, multithreading, windows-server-2008, 32bit-64bit

I am a newbie to Java and I have this app developed by someone else which is having some issues.
This Java app works well on windows xp 32 bit, but there is a delay while running on 64 bit windows 2008 R2 server. I have asked the customer to make sure that they are running the 32 bit version of JRE. I have checked the traces for the application and the application has an issue while calling a synchronized block always. This synchronized block adds the data into a queue from which it is picked up by some other process. I have checked the traces if some other process is using the block but it isn’t. The only confusing part is that the same app runs perfectly on windows xp 32 bit.

After googling I came to know that there are threading issues in win64

Help me with this.

Comment: how you are using synchronized block for two process????

Comment: All processes have their own streams. My synchronized block adds the data into a particular stream name provided as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer, but it might be of some help and it's more than a comment:

Most likely your 64 bit machine has more cores than the 32 machine, making it more likely that two or more threads really will run at the same time and any synchronization problems that never, or rarely, arise on the 32 will quickly pop up on the 64.  Also, newer machines tend to execute more instructions at once than older machines.  Both types reorder them as they do so.  (Also, compilers often reorder the code.)  So the 64's are a bit worse to start with, and when you throw in the more extensive, real multithreading the problems multiply.

(This can work the other way: the many-core machines tend to run threads in a predictable order, where a single core machine can wait many minutes to run something you expected would be executed immediately.)

I've usually found the best way to fix bugs is to stare at the code and make sure everything is precisely right.  (This works better if you know *when* something *is* precisely right.)  Failing that, you need logging messages that only print out when they're useful (it's hard to sort through a billion of them).  You seem to have no trouble reproducing your problems (which almost makes me think it may not be a multithreading problem at all), which should make it a bit easier to figure out.